# How former WebDriver.get() should wait for later WebDriverWait()?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

We all know that with WebDriver.get() alone, then the browser window opened up and closed very quickly after the command finished and our program will run the next commands. But I'm wondering how WebDriverWait() command should keep the browser window opening longer and load the page until some conditions fulfilled, even if  WebDriverWait() is executed AFTER WebDriver.get() finished?

Should we change the logical of calling/using these commands?

```
driver.get(url) 
# the windows browser opened up here and closed immediately 
# if we don't provide command WebDriverWait() below

element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'toggleIndex')) 

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
# with this command the opened browser window above will 
# lasting until element loaded.
```

Same with time.sleep():

```
driver.get(url) 
# the windows browser opened up here and closed immediately 
# if we don't provide command time.sleep() below

time.sleep(10) 
# with this command the opened browser window above will 
# lasting for 10 seconds.
```

Edit: Update about closing browser avoids misunderstanding

Comment: Can you update us why you are checking the presence_of_element_located() first, and then you use `eplicitWait` `WebDriverWait`

Comment: Please don't mind, because we could call WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'toggleIndex'))) instead

Comment: Yes I know, but how it keep the browser window opening longer? Please write a small program (with and without WebDriverWait/sleep) to test this by yourself to find out what I'm mentioning.

Comment: Then I don't know, sir. Because your answer is not fulfill my question. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you statement

> WebDriver.get() will close the browser after the command finished

is wrong, cause
it won't close the browser, rather it will load the provided URL in `get("string url")`, you may see the browser is getting closed cause you don't have any code after `.get()` or either you may have used `.close` or `.quit()` method.

Now coming to `WebDriverWait` which is basically explicit wait:-

> An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition
> to occur before proceeding further in the code. The extreme case of
> this is time.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period
> to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you
> write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in
> combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be
> accomplished.

You can read more about it [here as well](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

**Sample code  :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
search_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
#Now search_box is a web element, so you can do .click() or .send_keys() or infact any method which is avilable for web element in selenium.
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1:**

This is what Official doc says (regarding `.get()`):-

> The driver.get method will navigate to a page given by the URL.
> WebDriver will wait until the page has fully loaded (that is, the
> “onload” event has fired) before returning control to your test or
> script. Be aware that if your page uses a lot of AJAX on load then
> WebDriver may not know when it has completely loaded:

[Reference link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

**Update 2 :**

See, if this is your question :-

> I'm wondering how WebDriverWait() command should keep the browser
> window opening longer and load the page until some conditions
> fulfilled,

As mentioned before `WebDriverWait()` is known as Explicit wait, which means what ever you write here

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'toggleIndex'))
```

`WebDriverWait` will try to find this `ID` in `DOM`, if found immediately it would return the web element associated with that, if it does not find, it will try again after 500ms, and keep doing until a timeout occurred. This is to minimize the use of `time.sleep()` which will wait for exact time rather than dynamic waiting.

See the source code as well :

```
class presence_of_element_located(object):
    """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM
    of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
    locator - used to find the element
    returns the WebElement once it is located
    """
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
```

Comment: WebDriver.get() opens browser and load that url then close the browser.  Thanks for your answer but I don't ask how to use these commands. I wonder how it works inside the code. And I feel a bit confusing when using it.

Comment: `WebDriver.get() opens browser and load that url then close the browser. ` - see you did not mention this in your question at first place, so I thought you might be under the impression that it will `close` the browser. I have updated the answer above for `.get`. These `Webdriver` and `WebDriverWait` both are different component and they have their own use cases.

Comment: I updated the question. The update is about "closing browser window" to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: See the Update 2 answer above, I hope this will clarify your doubt.

Comment: You touched the mystic, please tell me how "Explicit wait" (sleep or WebDriverWait) keep browser window opening but another commands. And I found this a bit confusing and illogical vs canonical programming. Commonly, in a block, first command go first, and its "behavior" doesn't depend on the next command.

Comment: See, it has to execute those commands with a time interval so obviously browser will be opened till we have `webdriverwait`. Now having said that, Selenium is very fast as it usages HTTP client as a server to send and receive commands. But I am struggling to understand why does that matter ? which command is not getting execute without webdriverwait  ?

Comment: I meant another command don't keep the browser windows opening longer. Ok, as I said I feel it strange and want to know how. Please don't mind if you don't matter :D Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: other commands won't keep the browser window open, cause they won't wait for web elements in DOM, they would try to fetch it immediately, note that in this case it does not matter (if it fails or pass) the thing that matter is that they don't wait. it's just the wait component that can wait (as define in timeout ) little longer cause that's what they are meant for.